# Informix: count number of records with specific value?

Tags: sql, informix

I have this tables: PARTIDO, SUBLEMA, LISTA, REGISTRO_DE_VOTOS.

With this inner join statement:

```
SELECT partido.id_partido, sublema.id_sublema,lista.numero_lista
FROM partido INNER JOIN sublema ON 
     partido.id_partido=sublema.id_partido INNER JOIN 
     lista ON sublema.id_sublema=lista.id_sublema  INNER JOIN 
        registro_de_votos ON lista.numero_lista=registro_de_votos.numero_lista
```

I got the following result:

```
id_partido  | id_sublema| numero_lista
--------------------------------------
2           | 2         | 222
1           | 1         | 111
1           | 1         | 111
2           | 2         | 222
2           | 2         | 222
1           | 1         | 111
2           | 2         | 222
2           | 2         | 222
1           | 1         | 111
2           | 2         | 222
3           | 3         | 333
```

Is there a way to count the records for every id_partido?? So I can get somthig like this:

```
id_partido  | count
-------------------
1           | 4     
2           | 5     
3           | 1
```

The value of the column id_partido is not known. Could by any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
SELECT partido.id_partido, COUNT(sublema.id_sublema)
FROM partido INNER JOIN sublema ON 
 partido.id_partido=sublema.id_partido INNER JOIN 
 lista ON sublema.id_sublema=lista.id_sublema  INNER JOIN 
    registro_de_votos ON lista.numero_lista=registro_de_votos.numero_lista
GROUP BY partido.id_partido
```

The `GROUP BY` clause bundles all of the elements with the same `id_partido` and then the `COUNT()` function counts how many `id_sublema` for each `id_partido`

> If I use "SELECT partido.id_partido, COUNT(sublema.id_sublema) as cantidad ... " and then " ... ORDER BY cantidad DESC" I got the one with more records at the top. How I can only get the first of them??

You can use `TOP 1`

```
SELECT TOP 1 partido.id_partido, COUNT(sublema.id_sublema)
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!. If I use "SELECT partido.id_partido, COUNT(sublema.id_sublema) as cantidad ... " and then " ... ORDER BY cantidad DESC" I got the one with more records at the top. How I can only get the first of them??

Comment: It worked, but I changed TOP for FIRST. Thank you again.